# Чем отличается хруст от треска? Это не синонимы?

Tags: синонимы

Разве не что хрустит, то и трещит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев вряд ли тексты разграничивают эти понятия. Их употребляют как синонимы. Но предположу, что треск более резкий и выраженный звук. Скажем, еда может хрустеть за щекой, но не трещать. Трещит один раз скорлупа раскалываемого ореха, а потом его содержимым можно похрустеть. Ещё туда же: снег может хрустеть, но трещать он точно не будет, слишком сильный это звук.

Answer (score 0):

Самое основное различие:

Хруст - приятный (нераздражающий) звук.

Треск - неприятный звук.

В связи с тем, что громкие звуки раздражают, возникло следующее отличие:

Хруст - тихий звук.

Треск - громкий звук.

Это разные понятия. Но если слабослышащий человек услышит треск, то ему может показаться, что это хруст. Хруст может стать треском через микрофон и колонки.

Но если звук будет тихим, но очень неприятным - то скажут, что это треск.